# Failed Binding Queue Storage Message Text in Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-queues, azure-storage-queues

I have successfully sent some messages to Azure queue storage.

Here's a code of how I send messages to my queue storage:

```
private void QueueEmail(Email email)
{
    QueueClient client = GetQueueStorage("invoice-email");

    var message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(email);

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message);
    client.SendMessageAsync(message).Wait();
}
```

[image: Queue Storage]

The errors occur when I try to run the azure function to process the queue, the execution failed. Below are the error messages.
[image: Error me]

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're running into this issue is because Function is expecting a base64 encoded string and you're passing a simple string.

From this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=csharp#encoding):

> ### Encoding
>
> **Functions expect a base64 encoded string**. Any adjustments to the
> encoding type (in order to prepare data as a base64 encoded string)
> need to be implemented in the calling service.

Before sending the message, please try to convert that to a base64 encoded string. Something like:

```
private void QueueEmail(Email email)
{
    QueueClient client = GetQueueStorage("invoice-email");

    var message = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(email);

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message);
    client.SendMessageAsync(Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message))).Wait();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed solution! Never know the simple string is different from the base64 encoded string.